# Объясните смысл Context в Go

Tags: golang, context

Здравствуйте, уже второй день пытаюсь въехать в [`Context`](https://golang.org/pkg/context/), который практически везде используется в Go. Но не могу понять, для чего именно и какой смысл в его использовании. Статьи не помогают, походу я совсем безнадежен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Контекст - это просто сборник мета-данных, ассоциированных с каким-то запросом. Простейший пример - HTTP-запросы. Контекст пришедшего в HTTP-хендлер запроса отменяется, когда разрывается TCP-соединение. Предположим, ваш HTTP-хендлер делает какую-то сложную работу в цикле. Перед хендлером стоит промежуточный слой (middleware), которая берёт находит пользователя, например по куки, и кладёт в контекст запроса. Итоговый хендлер может выглядеть так:

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ctx := r.Context()
    user := userFromContext(ctx)
    if user == nil {
        http.Error(w, "no user", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            log.Printf("request cancelled: %v", ctx.Err())
            return
        default:
        }

        doSomethingSlow(i, user)
    }
})
```

Comment: Если честно, не совсем понятна вот эта конструкция - 
for i := 0; i < N; i++ {
        switch {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            log.Printf("request cancelled: %v", ctx.Err())
            return
        default:
        }

        doSomethingSlow(i, user)
    }

Comment: @IlyaNovikov Это просто эмуляция какой-то долгоиграющей работы, которую нужно уметь остановить, если пользователь отменил запрос.

Comment: ошибка в ответе, похоже нужен был не switch а [select](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/context/context.go#L87)?

Comment: @AntonK Fixed, спасибо.